# Microsoft Office Outlook Mail Search

Tags: email, search, outlook

How is it possible, that when I create a new mail and want to find the mail adress that the search not searching partial strings (Contains) than for begin of the mail-adress (StartsWith())???

This is not possible! Why I cannot search for mail adresses by partial string?

Stefan

Comment: How exactly you are searching? Please show the relevant snippets of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method of the `Namespace` class:

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("eugene") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 

Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

The method can also be used to verify a given name against an address book.